# Applying for Masters Program at University I work at as a Developer

Tags: masters, computer-science, career-path, non-academic-staff

I am currently a developer for a middle tier software company in the US. I have this job despite a bachelor's in economics. With my employers blessing, flexibility with working hours, but with my purse, I have been taking CS classes at a flagship state school here while working. I found that I really love taking CS classes and the formal learning!

Mean while, I have an offer at another uni as a full time developer as part of a grant funded team. One of the perks is covered tuition. My question is, should I decide to apply to graduate school for a CS Masters, does working as at the university as a developer affect the admissions process at all? For example, make acceptance somehow "easier"?

Comment: The answer *should* be that it doesn't matter, but it's probably up to the program to decide.  Ask them.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the university and its rules. General advice is probably worthless. It may be more lenient for an MS than a doctorate, perhaps. But the competition will still be there, and there may be specific rules about candidate selection.

I would expect that most places tuition reimbursement is a complete separate issue than placement into a program.

My advice, if you want an MS is to apply to more than one university. Include this one, of course, but don't cast a small net.

Comment: Unless the asker plans to move jobs, I would say heavily favor working and studying at the same institution. Just the lack of commuting time in the middle of the day will be invaluable. 

Of course, whether the MS program or job is more important depends on the asker's priorities in life.